# Function of adding two lists in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, arraylist, addition

whenever I run following code of adding two lists in python below mentioned error appears

```
    def add_lists(L1, L2):
        R = []
        for i in range(0, len(L1)):
            R.append(L1[i]+L2[i])
        return R

    L2 = [3, 3, 3, 3]
    L1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    add_lists(L1, L2)
    print("Resultant list of: ", str(L1), '& ' + str(L2), 'is', R)
```

---

this code yields **NameError: name 'R' is not defined**

Comment: The variable name `R` is defined within your function, but not outside it: that's why you see this error.  You should call your function and assign the result to a variable.  Say `res = add_lists(L1, L2)`.  Then you can use `res` in your `print` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `R` is local to your function and so is not accessible to your `print` statement.  (Generally, this is good!  It makes the function self-contained and avoids dependencies on what global variables may or may not exist.)

To print the result of the function, assign the result to an in-scope variable and use that.

```
def add_lists(L1, L2):
    R = []
    for i in range(0, len(L1)):
        R.append(L1[i]+L2[i])
    return R

L2 = [3, 3, 3, 3]
L1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
res = add_lists(L1, L2)  # assigns the result of the function call to a variable we can access
print("Resultant list of: ", str(L1), '& ' + str(L2), 'is', res)
```

Comment: It better to use *zip* to get two number from lists and add together, no need to use *index*...

Comment: Indeed.  Beyond OP's specific problem there are a few ways the code could be cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

You defined R in a local scope "it looks like inside a function" while you are trying to use it outside of that scope in the last line.

Try moving the initialization of "R = []" to the outer scope.

Answer (score 0):

its because R = [] is inside the function and print is outside the function...
so try this :

```
R = []
def add_lists(L1, L2):
        
        for i in range(0, len(L1)):
            R.append(L1[i]+L2[i])
        return R

L2 = [3, 3, 3, 3]
L1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
add_lists(L1, L2)
print("Resultant list of: ", str(L1), '& ' + str(L2), 'is', R)
```